# Images in table view change size when selected

Tags: ios, swift, image, select, tableview

The images that I added to my tableview are changing size when a cell is selected. I have found a lot of solutions but nothing worked for me. I use the 'built in' image view. I don't know if this is the problem? I would really appreciate it if you could help me :)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    //        cell.textLabel?.text = docArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: docArray[indexPath.row], attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.blue, NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 17)])
    cell.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 4
    cell.imageView?.downloaded(from: imageArray[indexPath.row])



    return cell
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you download the image here

```
cell.imageView?.downloaded(from:imageArray[indexPath.row])
```

1- Set

```
cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
```

2- Use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

```
cell.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageArray[indexPath.row]), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```